# How to set the tool bar title to center in android in java

Tags: android

```
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.gen_toolbar_pln);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
toolbar.setTitle(R.string.title_General);
```

I set the title for the tool bar in java. It is set to the left corner but I need to make this center.

How can I make this title center?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Using the standard toolbar provided by android it is not possible to move the title, you will need to create our own toolbar which can be as simple as a linear layout that has a gravity top with a child element that is a text view which is centered in parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to add a textview as a child to the toolbar

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: yes, but not with center_vertical

Comment: My bad, rectified it. Thanks @TimCastelijns